# Django-nonrel proper way to do update queries

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using django-nonrel on GAE.

For now update queries are not implemented in django-nonrel and if I try it will raise `NotImplementedError('No updates')`.

So what is the proper way to handle updates right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query for the records you want to modify, modify them yourself, and store them back to the datastore (preferably in batches).

Comment: You mean I should use GAE api?

Comment: @dragoon Presumably django-nonrel also provides ways to retrieve and store data. Otherwise it wouldn't be much of a database API.